# Prove that $x^2 + 3x +2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, but not in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

As the problem states, I need to show irreducibility of the given polynomial. I'm not sure where go with this, so any help would be great. I know that Eisenstein has a nice test for this in $\mathbb{Q}$, but this is in $\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to this is characterizing the units in $\Bbb Z[[x]]$.  If you don't know it already, you need to prove that $a_0 + a_1x + a_2a^2 + \ldots$ is a unit in $\Bbb Z[[x]]$ if and only if $a_0 = \pm 1$.

Comment: I think we have proved this result in class, so I'll see if I can find it in my notes. Thank you :) Since that is a result, I can site it directly and prove this very easily.

Answer (score 3):

Recall that power series (over a domain) is invertible if an only if its constant term is invertible; in this case this means constant term $\pm 1$.

Suppose $x^2 + 3x + 2$ is the product of two power series. Then $2$ is the product of the constant terms of these two power series. This is only possible if one of them is $\pm 1$ and thus invertible.

Reducibility as polynomial just boils down to searching the roots of the quadratic. You find the factorization $(x+1)(x+2)$.

Note: you also have that factorization for power series, but there $(x+1)$ is invertible.